# How can I make PHP SoapClient encode \n in entities

Tags: php, xml, soap

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends \n is not a valid character, in an xml text entity.  All \n's should be escaped to `&#xA;` or `&#10;` within the XML string.

However I am trying to send an email message, in a soap call, to my backend server, and line returns are being dropped.

So I'm starting with a parameter `$arguments` such that:-

```
error_log(__FILE_.':'.__LINE__.' '.var_export($arguments, true));
```

returns

```
array('email_parameters' => array ('email_message' => "Title\n\nBody\nSignature"));
```

I call `soapClient->__soapCall($method, $arguments);` and then log

```
error_log(__FILE_.':'.__LINE__.' '.var_export($this->soapClient->__getLastRequest(), true));
```

However, I'm getting `"<email_message>Title\n\nBody\nSignature</email_message>"`

Which is wrong according to the w3 rules.  If I try escaping the \n in advance, so `$argument` is

```
array('email_parameters' => array ('email_message' => "Title&#xA;&#xA;Body&#xA;Signature"))
```

then I get the following in the Request:-

```
<email_message>Title&amp;#xA;&amp;#xA;Body&#xA;Signature</email_message>`
```

So how can I get the soap client to correctly encode \n to `&#xA;`or `&#10;` and not double encode the html entity?

Comment: Try changing the single quotes 'Title\n\nBody\nSignature' to double quotes "Title\n\nBody\nSignature". PHP only looks for special characters in double quoted strings. Not sure if this is your problem. But I'd start there.

Comment: Nope, I was just typing the response to var_export, so it's not that.  PHP already encoded the argument going in properly.  Question is how to get it to encode the \n on the way out.

Comment: I've edited the question to use double quotes, just to keep it clear

Comment: Anyway you can post the part of the client that encodes it? Possibly you can extend it and turn off double_encode? Assuming it's using htmlentities.

Comment: That's what I'm doing until I find a better solution.  double html encoding it, seems to work.  I can see the & amp ;;xA; in the data, and that seems to work ok.